# pcb power connector lipo

Tags: pcb, connector, lipo

I have liPo battery with TAMIYA/TRAXXAS/DEANS/EC3
male adapters. Look at the picture:
[image]

But there is no luck to find some compatible pcb surface mount female 
connector to power up my board from liPo battery.
Any TAMIYA or TRAXXAS or DEANS or EC3 compatible female pcb connector?
Link me please!
I'm sorry if this subject matter is inappropriate for the site.

Comment: Those connectors are not intended for PCB use, due to the very high amounts of current they are expected to handle.

Comment: What if I need to power up 4 bldc from power distribution board? Should I use the second avalilable battery calble - JST-XH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably (I assume you searched a while and won't repeat that) a wire to wire, not a wire to board connector, so you are indeed not going to find one intended for mounting on PCBs. You should instead choose any appropriate (mainly current rating and mechanical sturdiness) wire to board connector and make an adapter cable. Making your own cables is by crimping is very straightforward and can save you a lot of trouble with mismatched lengths etc.
Alternatively you could cut the cable (not both wires at the same time though!) and fix a different connector on it.

Basically you should choose one or two kinds of connectors appropriate for your needs, buy a cheap crimping tool, wires in different colors and a handful of said connectors and crimps. This will save you trouble in the long run. 
It is probably a good idea to buy both the same connectors your PCBs have and a good wire to wire connector.

If you need help doing those things just ask another question.

Comment: There is my LiPo battery: http://www.teamorion.com/rocket-sport-4200-lipo-7-4v-tamiya-plug-en.html  with Venom Uni Plug cable with set of adapters and JST-XH cable. Did you mean that I must to use JST-XH to connect that battery to pcb? Not Venom Uni Plug via adapter? If so, what is the purpose of Venom power cable?

Comment: No that is not what I meant. The connector with the thinner wires (in this case JST-XH (this is an excellent series of connectors in my experience btw)) is there to balance the charge in the different cells, a task which should be done now and then (you can just measure each cell separately with a voltmeter and if they differ by 0.2V or so connect them to a balancer). The purpose of the power cable is just to deliver power to your application (e.g. motors). 
It would help if you could give data on how much current you need to handle and what your PCB actually is/which connectors it has.

Comment: Thank you for advices! Here is general question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230156/power-distribution-and-interfaces-bridging-between-set-of-boards-in-the-system Give me some advices please for that question)